# Use <select> in Twig / Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I have the following code in a .twig WordPress template:

```
<select id="filter-assessment-year">
<option disabled selected hidden>ASSESSMENT YEAR</option>
<optgroup label="Assessment Year">
    <option value="2022">2022 Assessment</option>
    <option value="2021">2021 Assessment</option>
    <option value="2020">2020 Assessment</option>
    <option value="2019">2019 Assessment</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I then need to output different code depending on which year the user selects. I want to basically say if user selects 2022 then output this code, else if user selects 2021 then output this code.

How can I use the above option selection to control the code output in my twig template?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript for this. Try a library like [Alpine JS](https://alpinejs.dev/) if you're not already using jQuery.

```js
const selectForm = document.getElementById('assesment');

selectForm.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(selectForm.value === '2022'){
     alert('2022 Code will run');
  }
  if(selectForm.value === '2021'){
    alert('2021 Code will run');
  }
  if(selectForm.value === '2020'){
    alert('2020 Code will run');
  }
   if(selectForm.value === '2019'){
    alert('2019 Code will run');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="assesment" class="target">
      <option value="0">ASSESSMENT YEAR</option>
      <option value="2022">2022 Assessment</option>
      <option value="2021">2021 Assessment</option>
      <option value="2020">2020 Assessment</option>
      <option value="2019">2019 Assessment</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thank you, this works in that in returns '2019 selected' as text underneath the selector. How could I control it so that a different version of my code outputs depending on which year has been selected? Thank you

Comment: Updated to run different code based on selected value.